# ExtUtils::MakeMaker including external *.mk and using defines within *.mk file for LIBS and INC parameters in WriteMakefile

Tags: c, perl, makefile, makemaker

I have a top level defines.mk file which lists certain directories and C libraries to include depending on the project like so.

```
KERNEL_LIB = -lkdev  
DRIVER_LIB = -ldriver -lutil -linit $(KERNEL_LIB)
DRIVER_INCLUDE = -I../../include
```

I use XS to allow perl scripts to access these libraries and MakeMaker to generate the Makefile which will link these libraries in. I want to make it such that when the Makefile is generated, it pulls in these defines.

Given a WriteMakefile like this

```
WriteMakefile(  
    NAME              => 'generic_scripts',
    VERSION_FROM      => 'generic_scripts.pm', 
    LIBS              => ['-L/usr/local/app/lib -lkdev -lpthread -lrt -ldriver -lutil -linit'],
    DEFINE            => '', 
    INC               => '-I../../include', 
    clean             => {FILES=>"*.o"},
);
```

I want to achieve this

```
WriteMakefile(  
    NAME              => 'generic_scripts',
    VERSION_FROM      => 'generic_scripts.pm', 
    LIBS              => ['-L/usr/local/dx/lib $(KERNEL_LIB) -lpthread -lrt $(DRIVER_LIB)'],
    DEFINE            => '', 
    INC               => '$(DRIVER_INCLUDE)', 
    clean             => {FILES=>"*.o"},
);
```

From @mobrule I now have this Makefile.PL

```
use 5.008008;
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;
use ExtUtils::MM_Unix;
use ExtUtils::MM;

sub MY::post_initialize {
    open my $defs, '<', 'defines.mk';
    my $extra_defines = join '', <$defs>;
    close $defs;
    return $extra_defines;
}

sub MM::init_others {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->ExtUtils::MM_Unix::init_others(@_);

    $self->{EXTRALIBS} = '-L/usr/local/app/lib $(DRIVER_LIB) -lpthread -lrt';
    $self->{BSLOADLIBS} = $self->{LDLOADLIBS} = $self->{EXTRALIBS};
}

WriteMakefile(
    NAME              => 'generic_scripts',
    VERSION_FROM      => 'generic_scripts.pm',
    DEFINE            => '',
    INC               => '$(DRIVER_INCLUDE)',
    clean             => {FILES=>"*.o"},
);
```

Which looks like it does what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a question in here?  What part are you having trouble with?  What have you tried?

Comment: Well, I'm just curious if there's a way to do it? Looking at documentation online it doesn't look obvious as none of the parameters to WriteMakefile can achieve this. I suppose I can pull in the defines.mk file into Makefile.PL and parse it but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `post_initialize` method to include your additional definitions:

```
sub MY::post_initialize {
    open my $defs, '<', 'defines.mk';
    my $extra_defines = join '', <$defs>;
    close $defs;
    return $extra_defines;
}
```

These will appear at the top of the Makefile, so later definitions (e.g. `LIBS`, can use them).

The next problem is getting MakeMaker to let the "invalid" entries in the `LIBS` and `INC` parameters passed through to the Makefile.

On Windows I think you can just put a `:nosearch`, like

```
LIBS => ['-lm', ':nosearch $(OTHER_LIBS)']
```

and it will pass through (consult the docs to `ExtUtils::Liblist`). On Unix-y systems that doesn't work, and you may need to do something more radical like overriding `init_others`:

```
sub MM::init_others {      # MM package is a subclass of ExtUtils::MM_Unix and will
                           # get called instead of ExtUtils::MM_Unix::init_others
    my $self = shift;
    $self->SUPER::init_others(@_); # invoke ExtUtils::MM_Unix::init_others

    # now repair the attributes that ExtUtils::MM_Any::init_others didn't set
    $self->{EXTRALIBS} = '-lkdev $(KERNEL_LIB) -lrt $(DRIVER_LIB)';
    $self->{BSLOADLIBS} = $self->{LDLOADLIBS} = $self->{EXTRALIBS};
    1; 
}
```

I haven't tested this and this might not be a complete working solution. Hopefully it will get you going in the right direction (if you are still reading this far).

Comment: For the post_initialize code, don't you want to return $extra_defines

Comment: Also sub MM::init_others should be MM_Unix::init_others.. right?

Comment: Also, I can pass the INC parameter fine apparently, its just the LIBS parameter.

Comment: @colekas - Yes of course return `$extra_defines`. But do use `MM::init_others` not `MM_Unix`. `MM` is a subclass of `MM_Unix` and you do (probably) want to invoke the original `MM_Unix::init_others`